# Please how do I create a JQuery playlist?

Tags: javascript, playlist

I'm working on a music streaming website using a theme I got. Everything is great except for the fact that the site is designed to only create a playlist using songs that the user plays and this is done by triggering a javascript event everytime the user clicks the play button. What I want is for a list of songs to be loaded on the playlist automatically once the user arrives on the page. Yu can see a sample at this link https://theplaylistnation.com/site/charts.php. What I want is for the songs on that page to load into the playlist before the play button is clicked so the user can listen non stop to all the songs on the Charts page. Please this would mean the world to me... Thanks, guys!

Below is the PHP script that lists the songs.

```js
window.Plyrist = {};
window.Plyrists = [];

(function($, undefined) {
  "use strict";

  Plyrist = function(el, items, options) {
    var self = this;
    this.active = 0;
    this.repeat = false;
    this.shuffle = false;
    this.items = items || [];
    this.oitems = $.merge([], items);

    this.el = $.extend({}, this._el, el);
    this.options = $.extend(true, {}, this._options, options);

    $.each(this.el, function(key, value) {
      if (key !== 'playlist' && key !== 'controls') {
        self.el[key] = self.el.playlist + ' ' + self.el[key];
      }
    });

    this._createControls();
    this._createItems();

    this.player = new Plyr(this.el.player, this.options);
    Plyrists.push(this.player);

    this.player.on('ready', event => {
      self._initEvents();
      self._initState();
    });

    this.player.on('play', event => {
      Plyrists.forEach(function(player) {
        if (player !== self.player) {
          player.pause();
        }
      });
    });

    this.player.on('loadedmetadata', event => {
      var duration = $(this.el.playlist + ' .plyr__time--duration');
      this.player.duration == 'Infinity' ? duration.hide() : duration.show();
    });

    this.player.on('ended', function() {
      if (self.repeat) {
        self._play(self.active);
      } else {
        if (self.items.length > 1) {
          self.next();
        } else {
          self.player.restart();
        }
      }
    });

    this._init();
  }

  Plyrist.prototype = {
    _el: {
      playlist: '#playlist',
      player: "audio",
      items: '.plyr-list',
      item: '.plyr-item',
      itemHtml: '<div class="plyr-item"><div class="plyr-item-poster"></div><div class="flex"><div class="plyr-item-title h-1x"></div><div class="plyr-item-author text-sm text-fade"></div></div><button class="plyr-item-close close text">&times;</button></div>',
      itemTitle: '.plyr-item-title',
      itemAuhtor: '.plyr-item-author',
      itemPoster: '.plyr-item-poster',
      itemClose: '.plyr-item-close',
      poster: '.plyr__poster',
      title: '.plyr__title',
      author: '.plyr__author',
      prev: '[data-plyr="prev"]',
      next: '[data-plyr="next"]',
      like: '[data-plyr="like"]',
      shuffle: '[data-plyr="shuffle"]',
      repeat: '[data-plyr="repeat"]',
      list: '[data-plyr="list"]',
      controls: {
        prev: '<button type="button" class="plyr__control" data-plyr="prev"><svg role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#plyr-prev"></use></svg><span class="plyr__tooltip" role="tooltip">Prev</span></button>',
        play: '<button type="button" class="plyr__control" aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Play, {title}" data-plyr="play"><svg class="icon--pressed" role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#plyr-pause"></use></svg><svg class="icon--not-pressed" role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#plyr-play"></use></svg><span class="label--pressed plyr__tooltip" role="tooltip">Pause</span><span class="label--not-pressed plyr__tooltip" role="tooltip">Play</span></button>',
        next: '<button type="button" class="plyr__control" data-plyr="next"><svg role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#plyr-next"></use></svg><span class="plyr__tooltip" role="tooltip">Next</span></button>',
        poster: '<div class="plyr__poster"></div>',
        title: '<a class="plyr__title ajax" href="#"></a>',
        author: '<div class="plyr__author"></div>',
        progress: '<div class="plyr__progress"><input data-plyr="seek" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0" aria-label="Seek"><progress class="plyr__progress__buffer" min="0" max="100" value="0">% buffered</progress><span role="tooltip" class="plyr__tooltip">00:00</span></div>',
        currentTime: '<div class="plyr__time plyr__time--current" aria-label="Current time">00:00</div>',
        duration: '<div class="plyr__time plyr__time--duration" aria-label="Duration">00:00</div>',
        mute: '<button type="button" class="plyr__control" aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Mute" data-plyr="mute"><svg class="icon--pressed" role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#plyr-muted"></use></svg><svg class="icon--not-pressed" role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#plyr-volume"></use></svg><span class="label--pressed plyr__tooltip" role="tooltip">Unmute</span><span class="label--not-pressed plyr__tooltip" role="tooltip">Mute</span></button>',
        volume: '<div class="plyr__volume"><input data-plyr="volume" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="1" autocomplete="off" aria-label="Volume"></div>',
        like: '<button type="button" class="plyr__control" aria-pressed="false" data-plyr="like"><svg class="icon--pressed" role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#plyr-liked"></use></svg><svg class="icon--not-pressed" role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#plyr-like"></use></svg><span class="label--pressed plyr__tooltip" role="tooltip">Dislike</span><span class="label--not-pressed plyr__tooltip" role="tooltip">Like</span></button>',
        shuffle: '<button type="button" class="plyr__control" data-plyr="shuffle"><svg role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#plyr-shuffle"></use></svg><span class="plyr__tooltip" role="tooltip">Shuffle</span></button>',
        repeat: '<button type="button" class="plyr__control" data-plyr="repeat"><svg role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#plyr-repeat"></use></svg><span class="plyr__tooltip" role="tooltip">Repeat</span></button>',
        list: '<button type="button" class="plyr__control" data-plyr="list"><svg role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#plyr-list"></use></svg><span class="plyr__tooltip" role="tooltip">Playlist</span></button>'
      }
    },
    _options: {
      theme: 0,
      iconUrl: '../libs/plyrist/src/plyrist.svg',
      autoplay: true,
      hideControls: false,
      fullscreen: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    _init: function() {
      var self = this;
      if (self.options.autoplay) {
        self._play(self.active);
      } else {
        self.select(self.active);
      }
    },
    _initState: function() {
      // to fix css when use audio player to play video
      $('.plyr--video', this.el.playlist + '.plyrist_audio').addClass('plyr--audio');
      this.shuffle ? $(this.el.shuffle).addClass('is--shuffle') : $(this.el.shuffle).removeClass('is--shuffle');
      this.repeat ? $(this.el.repeat).addClass('is--repeat') : $(this.el.repeat).removeClass('is--repeat');
    },
    _initEvents: function() {
      var self = this;

      $(this.el.prev).off().on('click', function() {
        self.prev();
      });

      $(this.el.next).off().on('click', function() {
        self.next();
      });

      $(this.el.like).off().on('click', function() {
        $(this).attr('aria-pressed', $(this).attr('aria-pressed') == 'true' ? 'false' : 'true');
      });

      $(this.el.shuffle).off().on('click', function() {
        self.shuffle = !self.shuffle;
        self._initState();
      });

      $(this.el.repeat).off().on('click', function() {
        self.repeat = !self.repeat;
        self._initState();
      });

      $(this.el.list).off().on('click', function() {
        $(self.el.playlist).toggleClass('open');
      });
    },
    _createControls: function() {
      if (this.options.controls) return;
      switch (this.options.theme) {
        case 0:
          this.options.controls = this._buildControls([
            this.el.controls.prev,
            this.el.controls.play,
            this.el.controls.next,
            this.el.controls.poster,
            '<div class="plyr__col">',
            '<div class="plyr__row">',
            '<div class="plyr__info plyr__row">',
            this.el.controls.title,
            this.el.controls.author,
            '</div>',
            this.el.controls.currentTime,
            this.el.controls.duration,
            '</div>',
            this.el.controls.progress,
            '</div>',
            this.el.controls.mute,
            this.el.controls.volume,
            this.el.controls.like,
            this.el.controls.repeat,
            this.el.controls.shuffle,
            this.el.controls.list
          ]);
          break;
        case 1:
          this.options.controls = this._buildControls([
            this.el.controls.poster,
            '<div class="plyr__col">',
            this.el.controls.title,
            this.el.controls.author,
            '<div class="plyr__row">',
            this.el.controls.play,
            this.el.controls.prev,
            this.el.controls.next,
            '<div class="plyr__row"></div>',
            this.el.controls.mute,
            this.el.controls.volume,
            this.el.controls.like,
            this.el.controls.repeat,
            this.el.controls.shuffle,
            this.el.controls.list,
            '</div>',
            '<div class="plyr__row">',
            this.el.controls.progress,
            this.el.controls.currentTime,
            this.el.controls.duration,
            '</div>',
            '</div>'
          ]);
          break;
        case 2:
          this.options.controls = this._buildControls([
            this.el.controls.progress,
            this.el.controls.poster,
            '<div class="plyr__col plyr__info">',
            this.el.controls.title,
            this.el.controls.author,
            '</div>',
            this.el.controls.repeat,
            this.el.controls.prev,
            this.el.controls.play,
            this.el.controls.next,
            this.el.controls.shuffle,
            this.el.controls.like,
            '<div class="plyr__row"></div>',
            this.el.controls.currentTime,
            this.el.controls.duration,
            this.el.controls.mute,
            this.el.controls.volume,
            this.el.controls.list
          ]);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      $(this.el.playlist).addClass('plyrist-theme-' + this.options.theme);
    },
    _buildControls: function(arr) {
      var self = this;
      if (self.options.iconUrl) {
        $.each(arr, function(key, value) {
          arr[key] = value.replace(/xlink:href="/g, 'xlink:href="' + self.options.iconUrl);
        });
      }
      return '<div class="plyr__controls">' + arr.join('') + '</div>';
    },
    _createItems: function() {
      var self = this;
      //get items from html
      if ($(this.el.item).length > 0) {
        $(this.el.item).map(function(i) {
          var item = $(this);
          self._initItemEvent(item);
          self.items.push({
            id: item.attr("data-id"),
            title: item.find(self._el.itemTitle).text(),
            author: item.find(self._el.itemAuhtor).text(),
            type: item.attr("data-type"),
            source: item.attr("data-source"),
            provider: item.attr("data-provider"),
            poster: item.attr("data-poster"),
            el: item
          });
        });
      }

      // build item html from array
      $.each(self.oitems, function(key, item) {
        self._buildItem(item);
      });
    },
    _buildItem: function(item) {
      var el = $(this._el.itemHtml);
      el.attr('data-id', item.id);
      el.find(this._el.itemPoster).css('background-image', item.poster);
      el.find(this._el.itemTitle).text(item.title);
      el.find(this._el.itemAuhtor).text(item.author);

      item.el = el;
      $(this.el.items).append(item.el);
      this._initItemEvent(item.el);
      return item;
    },
    _initItemEvent: function(item) {
      var self = this;
      $(item).on("click", function(e) {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var i = self.getIndex(id);
        if ($(e.target).is('.plyr-item-close')) {
          e.preventDefault();
          self._removeItem({
            id: id
          });
          return;
        }
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
          self.active = i;
          self._play(i);
        }
      });
    },
    _addItem: function(item) {
      var item = this._buildItem(item);
      this.items.push(item);
    },
    _removeItem: function(item) {
      var self = this;
      if (item.id == null) {
        return;
      }
      var index = this.getIndex(item.id);
      if (index > -1) {
        this.items[index].el.remove();
        this.items.splice(index, 1);
        if (this.active == index) {
          this.setIndex(self.active, function() {
            self._play(self.active);
          });
        }
      }
    },
    _play: function(index) {
      if (!this.items[index]) return;
      var source = this.items[index] && {
        type: this.items[index]['type'],
        sources: [{
          src: this.items[index]["source"],
          provider: this.items[index]["provider"]
        }]
      };
      this.active = index;
      this.player.source = source;
      this.player.play();
      this.select(this.active);
    },
    getItems: function() {
      return this.items;
    },
    setItems: function(items) {
      var self = this;
      this.items = items;
      $.each(self.items, function(key, item) {
        self._buildItem(item);
      });
    },
    select: function(index) {
      var item = this.items[this.active];
      $(this.el.item).removeClass('active');
      $(this.el.title).html(item.title);
      $(this.el.title).attr('href', item.uri);
      $(this.el.author).html(item.author);
      $(this.el.poster).css('background-image', 'url(' + item.poster + ')');
      item.el.addClass('active');
      $(document).trigger('refresh');
    },
    setIndex: function(index, callback) {
      this.active =
        index > this.items.length - 1 ?
        0 :
        index < 0 ? this.items.length - 1 : index;

      if (this.shuffle) {
        this.active = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.items.length);
      }
      if (callback) {
        callback();
      }
    },
    getIndex: function(id) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
        if (this.items[i].id === id) {
          return i;
        }
      }
      return -1;
    },
    getCurrent: function() {
      return this.items[this.active];
    },
    play: function(item, callback) {
      var i = 0,
        index, items = item;
      if (!$.isArray(items)) items = [item];
      while (i < items.length) {
        index = this.getIndex(items[i].id);
        if (index == -1) {
          this.add(items[i], !i);
        } else {
          if (items.length == 1) {
            if (index !== this.active) {
              this._play(index);
            } else {
              this.player.togglePlay();
            }
          }
        }
        i++;
      }

      if (callback) {
        callback();
      }
    },
    prev: function() {
      var self = this;
      this.setIndex(self.active - 1, function() {
        self._play(self.active);
      });
    },
    next: function() {
      var self = this;
      this.setIndex(self.active + 1, function() {
        self._play(self.active);
      });
    },
    add: function(item, play) {
      this._addItem(item);
      if (play == true) {
        this._play(this.items.length - 1);
      }
    },
    remove: function(id) {
      this._removeItem({
        id: id
      });
    }
  }

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="record col-12" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-category="Pop" data-tag="<?php echo $aqr['country']; ?>" data-source="<?php echo $row['songurl']; ?>">
  <div class="list-item r">
    <div class="media">
      <a href="artist.page.php?ref=<?php echo $aqr['id']; ?>" class="ajax media-content " style="background-image:url(<?php echo $row['cover']; ?>)">
      </a>
      <div class="media-action media-action-overlay">
        <button class="btn btn-icon no-bg no-shadow hide-row" data-toggle-class>
                                    <i data-feather="heart" class="active-fill"></i>
                                </button>
        <button class="btn btn-icon no-bg no-shadow hide-row btn-more" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <i data-feather="more-horizontal"></i>
                                </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-content text-center">
      <div class="list-body ">
        <a href="artist.page.php?ref=<?php echo $aqr['id']; ?>" class="list-title title ajax h-1x">
          <?php echo $row['songtitle']; ?>
        </a>
        <a href="artist.page.php?ref=<?php echo $aqr['id']; ?>" class="list-subtitle d-block text-muted h-1x subtitle ajax ">
          <?php echo $aqr['artist']; ?>
          <?php if(!empty($row['feature'])){ echo ', '.$row['feature'].''; } ?>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-action  show-row">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="px-3 text-sm text-muted d-none d-md-block num">
          <?php echo $row['duration']; ?>
        </div>
        <button class="song btn btn-icon no-bg no-shadow" data-toggle-class id3="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<i data-feather="x" class="active-primary" style="color: #c02afe;"></i>
                </button>
        <button class="btn btn-icon no-bg no-shadow btn-more" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <i data-feather="more-horizontal"></i>
                                </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What effort have you made to build your feature and what specifically isn't working as expected?  Currently it sounds like you're just defining requirements and looking to hire a programmer to write the code for you.  That isn't what we do here.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: There is obviously no reason to post PHP. Please click edit, scroll down and click edit above snippet and replace the PHP with ENOUGH rendered HTML to make a [mcve] and not this dump of code

Comment: If you just found some code on the web and you want us to edit it into something useful. no thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot auto play music in most browsers anymore, but once a user presses play on the website then you can change songs and start playing them without any issues.

I've made an example on how to change the song once it ends, hopefully this is what you were looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="player" controls onended="playNextSong()">
        <source src="song-1.wav" type="audio/wav">
    </audio>
    <script>
        var count = 0;
        function playNextSong() {
            var songs = ["song-2.mp3","song-3.mp3"];
            document.getElementById("player").setAttribute('src', songs[count]);
            count++;
            document.getElementById("player").play();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And if you want it to loop around, then just add when it reaches the end of your song array, then set the count to 0 again.

Comment: Thank you so much! WIll try this and see how it plays out.

Comment: If the code above was a solution, please mark is as the answer